# Accessing multiple PictureBoxes (or any form control) in Visual Basic?

Tags: vb.net, picturebox

So I'm making a game in VB for learning purposes and now I'm struggling with this problem:

I'm trying to do a For loop that draws the level map. However, I just can't seem to figure out it. This is an example of what I'm trying to do:

```
For index as integer = 1 to 192
    PictureBox(index).Image = bg(map(x,y)) 'this is causing me problems
    x=x+1
    if x=16 then
        x=0
        y=y+1
    End If
Next
```

But since PictureBox(index).Image doesn't seem to be the correct answer, it simply throws me an error.

Is there any way to do this?

EDIT:

Shortly, I need to set PictureBox.Image's from 1 to 192 like this without having 192 lines of code:

```
PictureBox1.Image = bg(map(0,0))
PictureBox2.Image = bg(map(1,0))
PictureBox3.Image = bg(map(2,0))
PictureBox4.Image = bg(map(3,0))
'etc....
```

Instead I wan't to set them in a For loop. I don't want to have extra lines of code.

EDIT2:

The PictureBoxes are added in the editor.

Comment: Your picture boxes are named PictureBox1 through PictureBox192? Also, did you create these programatically through your code or through the drag/drop toolbox? I see you are accessing PictureBox as an array but i'm not sure why, is this array declared somewhere?

Comment: Please explain what is the error and show how do you fill the PictureBox array

Comment: Your question is not at all clear. Please read [mcve].

Comment: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and...* "causing me problems" is not a clear description of the problem.  See [Ask]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the designer set the property `Tag` of each `PictureBox` to the string value composed by the `x` and `y` required to pass to the `map` function

For example:

- PictureBox1 should have the Tag property set to "0,0"
- PictureBox2 set the Tag property to "1,0",
- ....
- PictureBox17 will have the Tag property set to "0,1"

and so on until you have mapped all your pictureboxes with the correct values.

Then your code could be changed to

```
' Assuming the PictureBox are all childs of the Form
For Each pic in Me.Controls.OfType(Of PictureBox)()

    Dim tag = pic.Tag

    ' You could omit this check if you have only the pictureboxes
    ' set with a valid Tag property 
    if Not string.IsNullOrEmpty(tag) Then
       Dim xyCoords = tag.ToString().Split(","c)
       pic.Image = bg(map(Convert.ToInt32(xyCoords(0), 
                          Convert.ToInt32(xyCoords(1))))
    End if
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to make a huge assumption here and assume that you already have the PictureBox's on the form prior to reaching this code and they have Id's PictureBox1 through PictureBox192. The code would look like the following. You need to:
1. Retrieve the element by its ID
2. Cast/convert it from an object to a PictureBox 
3. Set it's Image property appropriately.

```
Dim pBox As PictureBox ' To store each pic box in
For index as integer = 1 to 192
    pBox = Me.Controls.Find(PictureBox&&index) ' Try to find pic box by ID
    If Not pBox Is Nothing Then ' If able to find element by this ID
        DirectCast(pBox, PictureBox).Image = bg(map(x,y))
    End If
    x=x+1
    if x=16 then
        x=0
        y=y+1
    End If
Next
```